# Get rid of "Caught an unhandled exception:" in exception response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, response

I have some logic in code to throw an error if something happen like this:

```
if(somethingHappned) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message for FE!");
}
```

and this is response from Spring Boot:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "Unhandled Exception",
            "message": "Caught an unhandled exception: Message for FE!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of

> Caught an unhandled exception:

in exception response?

Comment: Do not use exceptions for flow control, it's a bad practise. Put "do not use exceptions for flow control" to a search engine for more info. The message is a warning because you are not handling the exception so add an exception handler for the exception to get rid of the message. Leaking exception messages to API responses is a security issue as it allows attackers to learn information from your (missing) error handling.